# Removing the php extension doesn't work with other rules in mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Update**: Is `report` a reserved word or some sort of special string in mod rewrite? I have changed the file name to `report1` and the rules are working fine.

**Original Question**:

I cannot get a specific file `/www/admin/report.php` to work with my rewrite rules. I want to have the php extension removed and append a category value to the `/admin/` path, like this:

```
https://url.com/car/admin/report
```

But for some reasons the url only works with the extension present:

```
https://url.com/car/admin/report.php
```

I have uncommented the other rules to test. Here are the rules that should remove the php extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(admin|search)/(.*) 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$  $2/$3?category=$1 [NC,QSA] 
// I make it less specific so it works with any filenames other than report.php as well
```

I have tried adding `.php` to the last rule but that won't work either

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$  $2/$3.php?category=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your .htaccess placed in `/car/` directory? Also what is your last rule supposed to be doing? I don't see a requirement for `?category=...`

Answer (score 1):

You could try just using mod_negotiation, and ditch all your php extension rules. Just add the option somewhere in your htaccess file:

```
Options +Multiviews
```